# Найти все нужные переменные в коде и поменять их содержимое

Tags: python

У меня есть несколько переменных в названиях которых фигурирует слово ('string'). Количество переменных заранее не известно, но для примера рассмотрим количество 5. Я хочу у всех существующих переменных с названием 'string' сделать реплейс. Я попробовал найти все эти переменные через цикл

```
for i in globals():
    if 'string' in i:
```

Я получаю все нужные мне переменные, но сделать реплейс я в них не могу. Есть варианты как это сделать?)

```
Correct_SubNetwork = 'www'
Correct_MEID = 'xxx'
Correct_ENBFunctionFDD = 'zzz'
Correct_EUtranCellFDD_1 = 'yyy'


test_string1 = 'CREATE:MOC="UeEUtranMeasurement",MOI="SubNetwork=%SubNetwork%,MEID=%MEID%,ENBFunctionFDD=%ENBFunctionFDD%'
test_string2 = 'CREATE:MOC="UeEUtranMeasurement",MOI="SubNetwork=%SubNetwork%,MEID=%MEID%,ENBFunctionFDD=%ENBFunctionFDD%'
test_string3 = 'CREATE:MOC="UeEUtranMeasurement",MOI="SubNetwork=%SubNetwork%,MEID=%MEID%,ENBFunctionFDD=%ENBFunctionFDD%'
test_string4 = 'CREATE:MOC="UeEUtranMeasurement",MOI="SubNetwork=%SubNetwork%,MEID=%MEID%,ENBFunctionFDD=%ENBFunctionFDD%'
test_string5 = 'CREATE:MOC="UeEUtranMeasurement",MOI="SubNetwork=%SubNetwork%,MEID=%MEID%,ENBFunctionFDD=%ENBFunctionFDD%'


for i in range(1):          # цикл создан для того, чтобы добавить значение i в globals()
    print(i)

for i in globals():
    if 'string' in i:
        i = i.replace('%SubNetwork%', Correct_SubNetwork)
        i = i.replace('%MEID%', Correct_MEID)
        i = i.replace('%ENBFunctionFDD%', Correct_ENBFunctionFDD)
        print(i)
```

Comment: может, вам проще поменять инициализацию этих строк на f-строки?

Comment: Так `i` - это ж имя переменной. Зачем вы делаете replace в имени переменной, а не в содержимом? Содержимое же находится в словаре, что вернула функция `globals()`. Т.е. конкретно в вашем случае это  `globals()[i]`. Ну и вообще, зачем хранить что-либо в нумерованных переменных, если для этого можно завести, например, либо список, либо словарь?

Comment: @splash58 Обьясните плз поподробнее, если не сложно)

Comment: @GrAnd будет что-то типа словарь изменился во время итерации. Надо тогда накапливать в другой и делать update

Comment: @GrAnd Спасибо ! если обращаться к значению ключа, всё гуд. Упустил тот момент, что globals() это словарь... )

Comment: У вас нумерованные переменные. Не думали использовать просто список с доступом по индексу вместо этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать f-строки. Достаточно  поменять обычным редактором `%SubNetwork%` на `{SubNetwork}` и приписать f в начале строки инициализации

```
Correct_SubNetwork = 'www'
Correct_MEID = 'xxx'
Correct_ENBFunctionFDD = 'zzz'
Correct_EUtranCellFDD_1 = 'yyy'


test_string1 = f'CREATE:MOC="UeEUtranMeasurement",MOI="SubNetwork={SubNetwork},MEID={MEID},ENBFunctionFDD={ENBFunctionFDD}'
```

---

А если взять за основу ваш подход (что мне кажется весьма неудачным), то делать надо как-тотак

```
d = {}
k =  v = None
for k, v in globals().items():
    if 'string' in k:
        v = v.replace('%SubNetwork%', Correct_SubNetwork) \
             .replace('%MEID%', Correct_MEID) \
             .replace('%ENBFunctionFDD%', Correct_ENBFunctionFDD)
        d[k] = v

globals().update(d)
print(test_string4) # CREATE:MOC="UeEUtranMeasurement",MOI="SubNetwork=www,MEID=xxx,ENBFunctionFDD=zzz
```